# Unable to list target platform

Tags: android, unity3d, android-sdk

Всем привет! Скачал сдк манеджер, установил его, указал путь к папке, но выдает ошибку Unable to list target platform. Пересмотрел всю папку, сами sdk не нашел. Кто с этим сталкивался?

Comment: надо наверное еще поддержку для Unity скачать и установить, а-ля UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-5.3.5f1

Comment: Скачал, не помогло

Comment: именно для своей версии юнити?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем что скачал версию 25.2.5, переименовал tools, и забросил tools с версии 25.2.5